# Salesforce LWC to Application Connection

Tags: lightning-web-components

We are working on an application using LWC. The issue we are having is getting communication between the LWC and the main app. We have tried using a json post to the application is there a more standard LW way that we should be doing it?

Application Code:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <lightning:tabset>
        <lightning:tab label="Opportunity Details">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters" >
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-6 slds-border_left slds-border_top slds-border_right slds-border_bottom" style="width: 40%;">
                    <c:OpportunityPaneHeaderComponent/>
                    <span><c:OpportunityPaneComponent/></span>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-6 slds-border_left slds-border_top slds-border_right slds-border_bottom" style="width: 30%;">
                    <c:TaskItemDetailHeader/>
                    <span><c:ActivityDetailsComponent/></span>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-6 slds-border_left slds-border_top slds-border_right slds-border_bottom" style="width: 29%;">
                    <c:SalespathHeader/>
                    <span><c:SalesPathDetailComponent/></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--<div class="slds-grid slds-gutters" >
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
                    <c:SalespathHeader/>
                    <span><c:OpportunityPaneStep2/></span>
                </div>
            </div> -->
        </lightning:tab>
        <lightning:tab label="Report" title="">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
                    <c:SalesReportHeader/>
                    <span><c:OpportunityReportComponent/></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </lightning:tab>
    </lightning:tabset>
</aura:application>
```

Issue:

This component should pass data to the main application.

Component Code:

Below snippet has the application event which is not working.

```
<aura:component controller="OpportunityPaneController">
    <aura:handler value="{!this}" name="init" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="opportunityList" type="Opportunity[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="isShowTable" type="boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isShowDetails" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:registerEvent name="appEvent" type="c:OpportunityPaneEvent"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isAccRightArrow" type="boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isAccDownArrow" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="showStages" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="opptyId" type="String" default=""/>
    <div class="slds-brand-band slds-brand-band_medium" >
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isShowTable}">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr style="border: 1px solid;">
                        <th style="width: 40px;"></th>
                        <th style="width: 170px;">Account Name</th>
                        <th style="width: 120px;">Name</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Probability</th>
                        <th>Closed Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.opportunityList}" var="OpportunityRecord">
                        <tr style="border: 1px solid;">
                            <td >
                                <div id="{!'right:' + OpportunityRecord.Id}" onclick="{!c.accArrowClicked}" style="display:block;">
                                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:right" size="small"  />
                                </div>
                                <div id="{!'down:' + OpportunityRecord.Id}" onclick="{!c.accArrowClicked}" style="display:none;">
                                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:down" size="small" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div title="{!OpportunityRecord.Account.Name}">
                                    {!OpportunityRecord.Account.Name}
                                </div>
                                <div id="{!'stage:' + OpportunityRecord.Id}" style="display:none;">
                                    <table >
                                        <tr>
                                            <td >
                                                <div title="{!OpportunityRecord.StageName}" style="color:red;"><a style="color:red;" href="javascript:void(0);" id="{!OpportunityRecord.Id}" onclick="{!c.getRecordDetail}" >{!OpportunityRecord.StageName}</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td >
                                <div title="{!OpportunityRecord.Name}">{!OpportunityRecord.Name}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td >
                                <div title="{!OpportunityRecord.Amount}">
                                <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!OpportunityRecord.Amount}"/>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td >
                                <div title="{!OpportunityRecord.Probability}">{!OpportunityRecord.Probability}%</div>
                            </td>
                            <td >
                                <div title="{!OpportunityRecord.CloseDate}">
                                    <lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!OpportunityRecord.CloseDate}" day="2-digit" />/
                                    <lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!OpportunityRecord.CloseDate}" month="2-digit" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </aura:if>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

OpportunityPaneComp:

```
<aura:component controller="OpportunityPaneController">
    <aura:handler value="{!this}" name="init" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="opportunityList" type="Opportunity[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="isShowTable" type="boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isShowDetails" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:registerEvent name="appEvent" type="c:OpportunityPaneEvent"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isAccRightArrow" type="boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isAccDownArrow" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="showStages" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="opptyId" type="String" default=""/>
    <div class="slds-brand-band slds-brand-band_medium" >
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isShowTable}">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr style="border: 1px solid;">
                        <th style="width: 40px;"></th>
                        <th style="width: 170px;">Account Name</th>
                        <th style="width: 120px;">Name</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Probability</th>
                        <th>Closed Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.opportunityList}" var="OpportunityRecord">
                        <tr style="border: 1px solid;">
                            <td >
                                <div id="{!'right:' + OpportunityRecord.Id}" onclick="{!c.accArrowClicked}" style="display:block;">
                                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:right" size="small"  />
                                </div>
                                <div id="{!'down:' + OpportunityRecord.Id}" onclick="{!c.accArrowClicked}" style="display:none;">
                                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:down" size="small" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div title="{!OpportunityRecord.Account.Name}">
                                    {!OpportunityRecord.Account.Name}
                                </div>
                                <div id="{!'stage:' + OpportunityRecord.Id}" style="display:none;">
                                    <table >
                                        <tr>
                                            <td >
                                                <div title="{!OpportunityRecord.StageName}" style="color:red;"><a style="color:red;" href="javascript:void(0);" id="{!OpportunityRecord.Id}" onclick="{!c.getRecordDetail}" >{!OpportunityRecord.StageName}</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td >
                                <div title="{!OpportunityRecord.Name}">{!OpportunityRecord.Name}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td >
                                <div title="{!OpportunityRecord.Amount}">
                                <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!OpportunityRecord.Amount}"/>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td >
                                <div title="{!OpportunityRecord.Probability}">{!OpportunityRecord.Probability}%</div>
                            </td>
                            <td >
                                <div title="{!OpportunityRecord.CloseDate}">
                                    <lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!OpportunityRecord.CloseDate}" day="2-digit" />/
                                    <lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!OpportunityRecord.CloseDate}" month="2-digit" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </aura:if>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

OpportunityPaneController:

```
public class OpportunityPaneController{
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Opportunity> getOpportunityList(){
        List<Opportunity> listOfOpportunity = new List<Opportunity>();
        for(Opportunity objOppty : [Select Id,StageName,CloseDate,Amount,Account.Name,Name,Probability from Opportunity where OwnerId =: UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 5] ){
            listOfOpportunity.add(objOppty);
        }
        return listOfOpportunity;
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Task> getTaskList(String opportunityId){
        List<Task> listOfTask = new List<Task>();
        for(Task objTask : [Select Id,Account.Name,Owner.Name,IsClosed,Description,CreatedDate,ActivityDate,Priority,ReminderDateTime,Status,Subject,Type from Task where WhatId =: opportunityId]){
            listOfTask.add(objTask);
        }
        return listOfTask;
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Opportunity getOpportunity(String opptyId){      
        return ([Select Id,StageName,CloseDate,Amount,Account.Name,Name,Probability from Opportunity where Id =: opptyId]);
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getOpportunityJSON(String opptyId){
        List<Opportunity> listOfOpportunity = new List<Opportunity>(); 
        if(opptyId ==''){
            listOfOpportunity = [SELECT Id, StageName FROM Opportunity ];
        }else{
            String accIId;
            for(Opportunity objOppty : [Select Id,AccountId from Opportunity where Id =: opptyId]){
                accIId = objOppty.AccountId;
            }
            for(Opportunity objOppty : [Select Id,AccountId from Opportunity where AccountId =: accIId]){
                listOfOpportunity.add(objOppty);
            }
        }
        Map<String,Integer> mapOfLeadSourceAndCount = new Map<String,Integer>();
        for(Opportunity objOppty : listOfOpportunity){
            if(mapOfLeadSourceAndCount.containsKey(objOppty.stagename)){
                mapOfLeadSourceAndCount.put(objOppty.stagename, mapOfLeadSourceAndCount.get(objOppty.stagename)+1) ;
            }else{
                mapOfLeadSourceAndCount.put(objOppty.stagename, 0) ;
            }
        }
        List<ReportDataWrapper> listOfReportData = new List<ReportDataWrapper>();
        for(String key : mapOfLeadSourceAndCount.keySet()){
            ReportDataWrapper rdw = new ReportDataWrapper();
            rdw.name = key;
            rdw.y = mapOfLeadSourceAndCount.get(key);
            listOfReportData.add(rdw);
        }
        System.debug('listOfReportData:'+listOfReportData);
        return System.json.serialize(listOfReportData);
    }
    public class ReportDataWrapper{
        @AuraEnabled
        public String name;
        @AuraEnabled
        public integer y;
    }
}
```

OpportunityPaneComponentController:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getOpportunityList");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {            
            var state = response.getState();            
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.opportunityList" , response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.isShowTable" , true);
                component.set("v.isShowDetails" , false);

            }else if (state === "INCOMPLETE"){                

            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    getRecordDetail : function(component, event, helper){
        console.log('I am here');
        console.log(event.target.id);
        var opptyId = event.target.id;
        if(opptyId != ''){
            component.set("v.opptyId" , opptyId);
            var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:OpportunityPaneEvent");
            appEvent.setParams({"opptyId" : opptyId});
            appEvent.setParams({"isVisible" : true});
            appEvent.fire();
        }
    },
    refreshAction : function(component, event, helper){
        component.set("v.isShowTable" , true);
        component.set("v.isShowDetails" , false);
    },
    accRightArrowClicked : function(component, event, helper){
        console.log(event.target.id);
        //console.log('right arrow has been clicked');
        component.set("v.isAccRightArrow" , false);
        component.set("v.isAccDownArrow" , true);

    },
    accDownArrowClicked : function(component, event, helper){
        console.log('down arrow has been clicked');
        component.set("v.isAccRightArrow" , true);
        component.set("v.isAccDownArrow" , false);
        console.log(event.target.id);

    },
    accArrowClicked : function(component, event, helper){
        console.log(event.target.id);
        //console.log('right arrow has been clicked');
        var arrowId = event.target.id;
        var arrowAfterSplit = arrowId.split(':');
        var arrowName = arrowAfterSplit[0];
        var opptyId = arrowAfterSplit[1];
        console.log('arrowName: '+ arrowName);
        console.log('opptyId: '+ opptyId);
        if(arrowName =='right'){
            component.set("v.isAccRightArrow" , false);
            component.set("v.isAccDownArrow" , true);
            component.set("v.opptyId" , opptyId);
        }else{
            component.set("v.isAccRightArrow" , true);
            component.set("v.isAccDownArrow" , false);
            component.set("v.opptyId" , opptyId);
        }
        var idToShow;
        if(arrowName =='right'){
            var clickedArrowElement = document.getElementById(arrowId);
            console.log('clickedArrowElement:'+ clickedArrowElement);
            clickedArrowElement.style.display = "none";
            idToShow = 'down:' + opptyId;
            var stageIdToShow = 'stage:' + opptyId;
            var showArrowElement = document.getElementById(stageIdToShow);
            showArrowElement.style.display = "block";
        }
        if(arrowName =='down'){
            var clickedArrowElement = document.getElementById(arrowId);
            console.log('clickedArrowElement:'+ clickedArrowElement);
            clickedArrowElement.style.display = "none";
            idToShow = 'right:' + opptyId;

            var stageIdToShow = 'stage:' + opptyId;
            var showArrowElement = document.getElementById(stageIdToShow);
            showArrowElement.style.display = "none";
            if(component.get("v.opptyId") != ''){
                var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:OpportunityPaneEvent");
                appEvent.setParams({"opptyId" : component.get("v.opptyId")});
                appEvent.setParams({"isVisible" : false});
                appEvent.fire();
            }
        }
        console.log('idToShow: '+ idToShow);
        var showArrowElement = document.getElementById(idToShow);
        showArrowElement.style.display = "block";
    }
})
```

OpportunityApplication:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="showTaskDetailBoolean" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="showSalesPathDetailBoolean" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:handler event="c:OpportunityPaneEvent" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <lightning:tabset>
        <lightning:tab label="Opportunity Details">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters" >
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-6 slds-border_left slds-border_top slds-border_right slds-border_bottom" style="width: 40%;">
                    <c:OpportunityPaneHeaderComponent/>
                    <span><c:OpportunityPaneComponent/></span>
                </div>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showTaskDetailBoolean}">
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-6 slds-border_left slds-border_top slds-border_right slds-border_bottom" style="width: 30%;">
                        <c:TaskItemDetailHeader/>
                        <span><c:ActivityDetailsComponent/></span>
                    </div>
                </aura:if>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSalesPathDetailBoolean}">
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-6 slds-border_left slds-border_top slds-border_right slds-border_bottom" style="width: 29%;">
                        <c:SalespathHeader/>
                        <span><c:SalesPathDetailComponent/></span>
                    </div>
                </aura:if>
            </div>
            <!--<div class="slds-grid slds-gutters" >
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
                    <c:SalespathHeader/>
                    <span><c:OpportunityPaneStep2/></span>
                </div>
            </div> -->
        </lightning:tab>
        <lightning:tab label="Report" title="">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
                    <c:SalesReportHeader/>
                    <span><c:OpportunityReportComponent/></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </lightning:tab>
    </lightning:tabset>
</aura:application>
```

ActivityDetailComponent:

```
<aura:component controller="OpportunityPaneController">
    <!-- 
        <lightning:icon iconName="standard:task" />
        <lightning:icon iconName="standard:log_a_call" />
        <lightning:icon iconName="standard:email" />
        <lightning:icon iconName="standard:event" /> 
    -->
    <aura:handler event="c:OpportunityPaneEvent" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="opportunityRecord" type="Opportunity" />
    <div >
        <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
            <b>{!v.opportunityRecord.Account.Name}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
            PAST ACTIVITIES (listed by Stage in which they were created)
        </div>
        <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
            {!v.opportunityRecord.stageName}
        </div>
        <table >
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        6/15
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        <lightning:icon iconName="standard:email" />
                        Bill clicked on "Faster Forecasting" email campaign.
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        6/17
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        <lightning:icon iconName="standard:log_a_call" />
                        SDR Outbound call connect, Opportunity created.                     
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        6/17
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        <lightning:icon iconName="standard:email" />
                        EMAIL: "Faster Forecasting" white paper sent by SDR
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        6/22
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        Opportunity forwarded to Territory rep
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
            NEEDS ANALYSIS
        </div>
        <table >
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        7/1
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        <lightning:icon iconName="standard:log_a_call" />
                        Initial phone call w/Jerry.
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        7/6
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        <lightning:icon iconName="standard:log_a_call" />
                        Discovery call.                     
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        7/11
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        <lightning:icon iconName="standard:log_a_call" />
                        Timing confirmation call.
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        7/13
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        <lightning:icon iconName="standard:email" />
                        Email: agreed to move forward.
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        7/15
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        <lightning:icon iconName="standard:email" />
                        Email: sent timeframe suggestion.
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="slds-text-body_regular slds-text-color_success">
            Next Call Jeff to discuss status
        </div>
        <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
            - Timing still the same - August?
        </div>
        <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
            - Consensus w/team?
        </div>
        <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
            - Initial Pricing discussion
        </div>
        <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
            - His personal position on project?
        </div>
        <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
            Sales Path Questions:
        </div>
        <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
            What resources are available to implement the solution?
        </div> 
        <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
            Next STEPS
        </div>
        <table >
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        7/23
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        Check product roadmap for key feature
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        7/25
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                        <lightning:icon iconName="standard:log_a_call" />
                        Meeting in New York                     
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
            PROPOSAL
        </div>
        <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
            Future Phases
        </div>
        <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
            - add "Super-Note" container/component w/multiple Tasks, Activities, Notes in one Task
        </div>
        <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
            - Option to display "Past Activities" under "Next Steps" to align w/current Lightning UI
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: can you add code snippet?

Comment: It would also be helpful to understand if you application is something hosted outside of Salesforce or within Salesforce.

Comment: It's within salesforce

Comment: Anything that you do within Salesforce needs to be done either via UI API or Apex.